# convergence of series of sequence made by changing order.

Tags: sequences-and-series

There is a sequence ${a_1, a_2, a_3, ... }$. 
Suppose that the series of this sequence converges to a.

It is possible to make 1-1 function $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}.$

My question is,
${b_1, b_2, b_3, ... }$ where $b_i = a_j$ , $j = f(i)$. Then Does the series of ${b_n}$ converge to a?

I think that it is true, but I don't know how to prove it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking about is so called conditional convergence. It turns out that a series may or may not converge (un)conditionally and it depends on whether the sum of the absolute values

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_i|
$$
converges, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem for a detailed discussion.